# Xamarin Native Android HttpClient, where is it located?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, httpclient, androidhttpclient

When i select the native implementation for the **HttpClient** in Visual Studio like:

[image: selection of HttpClient]

And i use the **HttpClient** in my code.

- where does the HttpClient code live ?
- Is it in a native Android library ?
- Or is it in the Google Play Services ?
- Where could I find out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### HttpClient implementation:

> where does the HttpClient code live ?

`HttpClient` is the "normal" `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, but when using the `AndroidClientHander` there is a custom `System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler` that uses `Java.Net.HttpURLConnection` as its implementation:

Re: [xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/f8c126a8ec135fa8e8c9830dcbceed485be07f5c/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs)

#### SSL/TLS implementation:

> Is it in a native Android library ?

As far as the "native" TLS 1.2+ option, it is provided by a bundled version of Google's Boring SSL ([boringssl](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl)) which is included in your `apk` (it is a native NDK/C shared library)